# How to Filter Data for 2 conditions in R?

Tags: r, filter, filtering

I have a set of data I need to filter to only keep rows with a score of at least 5 in at least 3 columns.

```
              Cluster_ID       1         2        3         4        5        6
 1 chr5:100468296..100468297,+ 0.43595 11.285500 0.000000  2.216480 0.000000  0.000000
 2 chr5:100469033..100469074,+ 0.08719  1.203780 0.393488  2.014980 0.478505  1.995390
 3 chr5:100496827..100496912,+ 0.34876  1.053310 1.180460  0.805992 0.837383  0.798157
```

I think I have been able to get the rows with scores of at least 5 by doing this:

```
CAGE_filter[!CAGE_filter[,2:7]>=5]
```

But, I am not sure how to filter it to go through the columns. I am new to R, could someone please tell me if I am on the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We first create a logical data.frame where each cell is TRUE if it's >= 5. We count the TRUE cells by row. We select only rows which have at least 3 TRUE cells. Providing your data.frame is called `d`:

```
d[apply(d[,2:7] >= 5,1,sum) >= 3,]
```

In your example data, it would return an empty data.frame since there are no such rows.

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `rowSums`to create the logical condition and filter the rows of the dataset 'd'.

```
 d[rowSums(d[2:7] >= 5, na.rm=TRUE) >=3,]
```